# Disable/Remove Table Index for INSERT Performance

Tags: performance, innodb, optimization, mysql-5.6, maintenance

I am doing a database maintenance where I have to add new fields to a table with over 10GB of data about (20 million rows). To solve that I renamed `tableA` to be `old_tableA` and created a new table called `new_tableA` and added new columns for this table as the this [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44777/how-to-add-column-to-big-table-in-mysql) has suggested.

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688731/is-it-better-to-create-an-index-before-filling-a-table-with-data-or-after-the-d), disabling table indexes and re-enabling them later would improve performance for `INSERT` transactions.

If I have `old_tableA` and `new_tableA`, where I would want to transfer all the rows from `old_tableA` to `new_tableA`, should I disable/remove the `INDEX`es in both of these tables?

I am using:

- MySQL 5.6
- InnoDB

Comment: Would be real nice to know.  Seems like a simple thing to do, but not even one answer.